# Best practice after adding,deleting,updating record to database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

It is practical / logical question about React state.

Lets say I have a database with 10 users and 100 books.

Application very simple, To make it easier to explain.

On homepage load I read all books information using componentOnDidMount() and I add it to my react state after that I display that data to users.

One of the users wants to add addition book to database. He adds book, gets response from server and here where my confusion starts.

A: Is it better to get that response of that one book was added from server and add it to current state state that user has.

B: Or is it better to make a request to database again to read all books again and update state this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd go with option A - after you get a 200 OK back, add it to the existing state. Unless you need real-time data for every book in the database, it'd be a lot more performant.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with updating the state once the record has been successfully created. Re-querying all the records will be unsustainable as your data set grows, and as @bpolly noted it will take a lot less compute to handle it this way.

Comment: Yes I am for option A as well because of better performace. Just want to know more opinions about B option. lets say 10 users going to add books, so it means Im going to see them only after refreshing my page.

Comment: If you want to build a real-time app like that, one that will update immediately when other users besides yourself interact with it, you'll need to implement something that maintains a constant connection, like a websocket: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket